# How do you wrap and use MarqueeLabel in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, marquee

I'm trying to add a marquee effect to a Text (song name) in SwiftUI, so that it scrolls horizontally across the screen if it is larger than the screen width.

I know [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) is available for UIKit, but I haven't been able to wrap it in SwiftUI or find an alternative that works.

Help?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Maybe wrapping in UIViewRepresentable? [How to wrap a custom UIView for SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-wrap-a-custom-uiview-for-swiftui)

Comment: Yeah, I actually followed those exact instructions. For some reason the view was stretching beyond the width of my screen.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but for anyone who has the same question. You can wrap this in an `UIViewRepresentable`. like so:

```swift
struct UILabelView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var text: String

    typealias UIViewType = MarqueeLabel

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UILabelView>) -> MarqueeLabel {
        
        let label = MarqueeLabel()
        label.text = text
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        return label
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MarqueeLabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UILabelView>) { }
    
}
```

and then if you have a view which has a limited with it should work:

```swift
UILabelView(text: "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20")
                .frame(width: 40)
```

As for your issue in your comment "For some reason the view was stretching beyond the width of my screen." the key is to use `.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)` on the MarqueeLabel as explained by @Asperi in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72855423/using-uiviewrepresentable-to-wrap-marqueelabel-view).